# For Loopを使ってリストをデータフレームに格納する方法

Tags: python, python3, dataframe

下記のような構成のリストをfor loopを使ってデータフレームに格納したいのですが、リストの中にあるリストをうまく抽出することができません。

```
[{'sitemap': [{'path': 'http://test.com/siteindex.xml',
    'lastSubmitted': '2017-09-28',
    'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '4225'}]}]},
 {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://example.com/siteindex.xml',
    'lastSubmitted': '2023-07-01',
    'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '2939'}]}]}
]
```

以下を試したのですがエラーが返ってきてしまいます。

```
data_for_df = []

for each in sitemaps_all:
  temp = []
  temp.append(each['sitemap'][0]['path']
  temp.append(each['sitemap'][0]['lastSubmitted'])
  temp.append(each['sitemap'][0]['contents'][0]) ##'type'を列として抽出
  temp.append(each['sitemap'][0]['contents'][1]) ##'submitted'を列として抽出
  
  data_for_df.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_for_df, columns =['path','lastSubmitted','type','submitted'])
```

どうすればデータフレームに変換することができるでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「どうすればデータフレームに変換することができるでしょうか？」とのことですが、欲しいデータフレームを提示いただけると回答しやすくなるかと思います。
また、「以下を試しましたのですがエラーが返ってきてしまいます。」についてエラーメッセージを質問に追記してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

sitemaps_all = [
    {'sitemap': [{'path': 'http://test.com/siteindex.xml',
                  'lastSubmitted': '2017-09-28',
                  'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '4225'}]}]},
    {'sitemap': [{'path': 'https://example.com/siteindex.xml',
                  'lastSubmitted': '2023-07-01',
                  'contents': [{'type': 'web', 'submitted': '2939'}]}]}
]

data_for_df = []

for each in sitemaps_all:
    temp = []
    temp.append(each['sitemap'][0]['path'])
    temp.append(each['sitemap'][0]['lastSubmitted'])
    temp.append(each['sitemap'][0]['contents'][0]['type']) ##'type'を列として抽出
    temp.append(each['sitemap'][0]['contents'][0]['submitted']) ##'submitted'を列として抽出
  
    data_for_df.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_for_df, columns =['path','lastSubmitted','type','submitted'])
print(df)

#                                 path lastSubmitted type submitted
# 0      http://test.com/siteindex.xml    2017-09-28  web      4225
# 1  https://example.com/siteindex.xml    2023-07-01  web      2939
```

Comment: 解決しました。実際のリストはもっと長いのですが、一部データが欠けていることが原因でfor loopが実行できていないということがわかりました。ありがとうございました。